# Generic circle reference due to constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to build 3 generic interfaces where one of them has generic contraints to the other two and those in turn have constraints to this third one:

```cs
public interface IUser<TUserRole> 
    where TUserRole : IUserRole<IUser<TUserRole>, IRole<TUserRole>>
{
    public IEnumerable<TUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public interface IRole<TUserRole> 
    where TUserRole : IUserRole<IUser<TUserRole>, IRole<TUserRole>>
{
    public IEnumerable<TUserRole> Users { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserRole<TUser, TRole> 
    where TUser : IUser<IUserRole<TUser, TRole>> 
    where TRole : IRole<IUserRole<TUser, TRole>>
{
    public TUser User { get; set; }
    public TRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

This does not compile with the error which basically says that there is no implicit converstion from

`IUserRole<TUser, TRole>`

to

`IUserRole<IUser<IUserRole<TUser, TRole>>, IRole<IUserRole<TUser, TRole>>>`

which shouldn't be the case because the `IUserRole` is in fact exactly that if I'm not mistaken.

This seems to be a simple task. Am I missing something here?

Comment: While I do know that this was quite some time ago I still wanna give tgis a try. I do however wanna know what the general purpose was behind "binding" them all together.